# Task 3 – Upload an AppBundle to Design Automation - Http Request Power Automate - Autodesk Forge

Tags: xmlhttprequest, autodesk-forge, power-automate, forge, autodesk-designautomation

`https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/autocad/task3-upload-appbundle/`

How do I implement the task 3 using power automate?

I'm having problems in the Upload of the AppBundle by Http.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>POST requires exactly one file upload per request.</Message><ArgumentName>file</ArgumentName><ArgumentValue>0</ArgumentValue><RequestId>2N9YNZ2J8M7CSDN0</RequestId><HostId>GH6fZMc9G4lqD5/VdQX3tdkTXoXRDO7Sm0qKK0jtHGLWt7PFBrki2fzhj1YKR4P4mkfG6+VMTRk=</HostId></Error>
```

**Process flow **

```
HTTP - Register AppBundle > (Check) 

Get file Content using path - ZIP File Content  > (Check) 

Compose - Create boundary > (Check) 

Compose - Create Multipart Content > (Check) 

HTTP - Upload AppBundle > (error)
```

**Compose.:**

- Create Boundary:

```
concat('----------', guid())
```

- Create Multipart content:

```
concat(
    '----------', outputs('Create_boundary'), '\r\n',
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"\r\n\r\n',
    body('Parse_JSON')?['uploadParameters']?['formData']?['key'], '\r\n',
    '----------', outputs('Create_boundary'), '\r\n',
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content-type"\r\n\r\n',
    body('Parse_JSON')?['uploadParameters']?['formData']?['content-type'], '\r\n',
    '----------', outputs('Create_boundary'), '\r\n',
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="policy"\r\n\r\n',
    body('Parse_JSON')?['uploadParameters']?['formData']?['policy'], '\r\n',
    '----------', outputs('Create_boundary'), '\r\n',
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="success_action_status"\r\n\r\n',
    body('Parse_JSON')?['uploadParameters']?['formData']?['success_action_status'], '\r\n',
    '----------', outputs('Create_boundary'), '\r\n',
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="success_action_redirect"\r\n\r\n',
    body('Parse_JSON')?['uploadParameters']?['formData']?['success_action_redirect'], '\r\n',
    '----------', outputs('Create_boundary'), '\r\n',
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x-amz-signature"\r\n\r\n',
    body('Parse_JSON')?['uploadParameters']?['formData']?['x-amz-signature'], '\r\n',
    '----------', outputs('Create_boundary'), '\r\n',
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x-amz-credential"\r\n\r\n',
    body('Parse_JSON')?['uploadParameters']?['formData']?['x-amz-credential'], '\r\n',
    '----------', outputs('Create_boundary'), '\r\n',
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x-amz-algorithm"\r\n\r\n',
    body('Parse_JSON')?['uploadParameters']?['formData']?['x-amz-algorithm'], '\r\n',
    '----------', outputs('Create_boundary'), '\r\n',
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x-amz-date"\r\n\r\n',
    body('Parse_JSON')?['uploadParameters']?['formData']?['x-amz-date'], '\r\n',
    '----------', outputs('Create_boundary'), '\r\n',
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x-amz-server-side-encryption"\r\n\r\n',
    body('Parse_JSON')?['uploadParameters']?['formData']?['x-amz-server-side-encryption'], '\r\n',
    '----------', outputs('Create_boundary'), '\r\n',
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x-amz-security-token"\r\n\r\n',
    body('Parse_JSON')?['uploadParameters']?['formData']?['x-amz-security-token'], '\r\n',
    '----------', outputs('Create_boundary'), '\r\n',
    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="ListLayers.zip"\r\n',
    'Content-Type: application/zip\r\n\r\n',
    base64(body('Get_file_content_using_path')), '\r\n',
    '----------', outputs('Create_boundary'), '----------'
)
```

**
Upload the AppBundle**

```
{
    "inputs": {
        "method": "POST",
        "uri": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['uploadParameters']?['endpointURL']",
        "headers": {
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "Content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=@{outputs('Create_boundary')}"
        },
        "body": "@outputs('Create_multipart_content')"
    },
    "metadata": {
        "operationMetadataId": "ad843c49-663f-44b1-bdde-62dd853a84b3"
    }
}
```

How can i correct this?

I tried with and withou base64 and other variants of the Http request.

I expect something like in the [tutorial](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/autocad/task3-upload-appbundle/)

```
curl -X POST \
  https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -F key=apps/myacad_app_11102019/ListLayers/1 \
  -F content-type=application/octet-stream \
  -F policy=eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjo... (truncated) \
  -F success_action_status=200 \
  -F success_action_redirect= \
  -F x-amz-signature=6c68268e23ecb8452... (truncated) \
  -F x-amz-credential=ASIATGVJZKM3ODN2W... (truncated) \
  -F x-amz-algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 \
  -F x-amz-date=20191014T061752Z \
  -F x-amz-server-side-encryption=AES256 \
  -F x-amz-security-token=AgoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEO7/////... (truncated) \
  -F file=@path/to/your/AppBundle/zip`
```

Comment: Try to use an endpoint generated by e.g. https://webhook.site/ and send the request there. Then you can analyze what exactly is being sent out from Power Automate which might help find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

did you modify the binary data of the file in any way? The file has to be sent as-is, without any encoding or modification to its binary data.